# Magento 2 customer login from external

Tags: magento2, login, customer-account

I've spend a lot of time to find simple solution for this problem:

- I can access to magento site from my mobile app using REST
- I have all customer data (email, pass, rest token, id), from APP
- I can create cart with some items with REST

After this, i need open external browser without need login (using existing customer data) with "checkout" url

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found temporary solution but I think is not right method:

/app/code/Marterosso/Autologin/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Marterosso\Autologin\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $objectManager;
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {

        $this->objectManager = $context->getObjectManager();
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $_params =  $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $q = ( isset($_params["q"]) && !empty($_params["q"]) ) ? $_params["q"] : false;
        if ($q) {
            $params = [];
            parse_str(base64_decode($q), $params);

            $email = ( isset($params["username"]) && !empty($params["username"]) ) ? $params["username"] : false;
            $password = ( isset($params["password"]) && !empty($params["password"]) ) ? $params["password"] : false;

            if ($email && $password) {

                /* @var $customerAccountManagement \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface */
                $customerAccountManagement = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface'); 
                $customerSession = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');  
                try {
                    /* @var $customer \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface */
                    $customer = $customerAccountManagement->authenticate($email, $password);
                    $websiteId = $customer->getWebsiteId();

                    /* @var $_customer \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer */
                    $_customer = $this->objectManager
                            ->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')
                            ->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

                    $customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($_customer->loadByEmail($email));

                    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart/');   


                } catch(\Magento\Framework\Exception\InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $ex) {
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

/app/code/Marterosso/Autologin/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="autologin" id="autologin">
            <module name="Marterosso_Autologin"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

/app/code/Marterosso/Autologin/etc/module.xml

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Marterosso_Autologin" setup_version="1.0.0">

    </module>
</config>
```

/app/code/Marterosso/Autologin/view/frontend/layout/autologin_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
           <container name="customer.login.container" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="form/login.phtml">
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Info" name="customer.new" template="newcustomer.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

/app/code/Marterosso/Autologin/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Marterosso_Autologin',
    __DIR__
);
```

Any other suggestions ?